# Issue with TabHost and Async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-tabhost

I have an app that uses an aSync task to mine some HTML data and it was working fine until i try to work with TabHost on my app. The thing is, when i try open this Tab, it pops out the ProgressDialog but after a moment it enters on a catch inside the `doInBackground`method, and the Exception is null, not NullPoint, just `e=null` and doesn't set the adapter with the data from the mining. Here's some code:

```
onCreate(){
   ...
   this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Downloading..",
            "Downloading...", true, false);
    this.pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    this.pd.setCancelable(true);
    ...
    task  = new DownloadTask().execute("Starting");
}
```

And

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

    protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {
        search = new Search(person);
        try {
            search.Login();
            data = search.ParseData();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            erroUnknown = true;
        }
        adapter = new RowAdapter(DataActivity.this, data);
   }
 }
```

And the tabActivity:

```
public class TabMenu extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DataActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("data")
            .setIndicator("Data",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    //Just test
            spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("artists")
            .setIndicator("Artists",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

}
```

Any idea why its entering the catch block? Do I have to adapt some code when using tabActivity?

Thanks in advance

Update:
While debugging sometimes, i got e=IllegalStateException from the entity.getContent(), even if it was the first time to be called. and StringOutOfBoundsException because the content is not fetching the correct data, i mean, without the tabs it logs in, and works the page, but with the tabHost it doesn't, how does it affected by tabHost?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, was an Intent passed by another Activity that had to be passed to the TabActivity..